# Django REST framework: get last related object

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get the last related object in a Django REST framework view.

With the current implementation I am getting this error - but I am not sure if this is the correct approach:

```
`HyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.
```

I have this two models (little bit cleaned up):

```
class Device(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

    def get_last_status(self):
        return self.status.last()

class DeviceStatus(models.Model):
    class eDeviceStatus(models.TextChoices):
        OFFLINE = 'F', _('Offline')
        ONLINE = 'L', _('Online')

    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, related_name='status', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=eDeviceStatus.choices, default=eDeviceStatus.OFFLINE)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()
```

with this `Device` view:

```
class DeviceViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = DeviceSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Device.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

and this `Device` serializer:

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    last_status = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'name', 'last_status']

    def get_last_status(self, obj):
        s = obj.get_last_status()
        serializer = DeviceStatusSerializer(s)
        return serializer.data
```

I would like to have in my api the last status (field: `last_status`) from the DB. But I am failing to have it correctly implemented. How can I have the `last_status` correctly set?

Comment: can you add DeviceStatusSerializer?